# MongoDB find query with combination of $or and $and in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to get rows where:

```
{repair field has "ac" OR {repair is "tv" and phone field in range 1091-1100}}
```

I am trying the following query:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
conditions := M{"name": M{"$regex": "me"},
    "$or": []M{M{"repair": M{"$eq": "ac"}},
"$and": []M{M{"repair": M{"$eq": "tv"}}, M{"phone": M{"$gte": 1091, "$lte": 1100}}}}}
    fmt.Println(conditions)
    err = c.Find(conditions).Sort("phone").Limit(20).All(&j)
```

However, I am getting a compile error:

```
index must be non-negative integer constant
cannot use []M literal (type []M) as type M in array or slice literal.
```

Comment: what lib are you using for mongodb?

Comment: What is the type of `j`?

Comment: i am using package gopkg.in/mgo.v2 and j is var j []M

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one `M{` before `"$and"` and after you add that don't forget to add another closing brace `}`.

[the good](https://play.golang.org/p/ByUQnJSJT5) and [the bad](https://play.golang.org/p/MP2CN6L9lq) for comparison.

Comment: thank you very much mkopriva. I just started coding in Go(1month)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what driver your using, but I would probably do something like this..

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

const (
    databaseString = ""
)

var db DataStore

type DataStore struct {
    Session *mgo.Session
}


// database
func (ds *DataStore) ConnectToDB() {

    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:   []string{"localhost:27017"},
        Timeout: 1 * time.Hour,
    }

    sess, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        sess.Refresh()
        panic(err)
    }
    sess.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    db.Session = sess
}

// J is the expected mongo return object
type J struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id"`
    // example data below
    Status string `bson:"status" json:"status"`
}

func init() {
    db.ConnectToDB()
}

func main() {
    colectionString := ""
    // probably best if this was a mapped mgo struct see above
    // var j bson.M

    var j J

    // your orignal code
    // I don't know why you are using $eq couldn't you just do bson.M{"repair":"ac"}, and bson.M{"repair":"tv"}
    conditions := bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$regex": "me"},
        "$or": []bson.M{
            bson.M{"repair": bson.M{"$eq": "ac"}},
        },
        "$and": []bson.M{
            bson.M{"repair": bson.M{"$eq": "tv"}},
            bson.M{"phone": bson.M{"$gte": 1091, "$lte": 1100}},
        }}

    err := db.Session.DB(databaseString).C(colectionString).Find(conditions).Sort("phone").Limit(20).All(&j)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I would probably also end up creating a separate package for the mongo connection stuff so that I can write wrapper functions around calls,

```
func FindItem(db *mgo.Session, id string) (data, error) {
    defer sess.Close()
    var res data //some data type struct
    err := sess.DB("my db").C("my collection").Find(bson.M{"user": someID}).One(&data)
    return data, err
}
```

then I'd be able to do things like this, which allow for concurrency

```
res, err := packagemain.FindItem(sess.Copy(), someID)
```

and your original code your you where missing `}` and `,`.  I suggest you use `go vet` or an ide which vets the code for you.  Also, `mgo` is the mongo driver you probably what you want to be using if you're not using it already.

Comment: thank you reticentroot. This is much cleaner than mine and also replacing eq with :